# Vertically align in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I'm working on a small site and I can't seem to figure out how to center my name vertically. I put my CSS in the HTML file, just so you can see everything I'm doing. Thanks in advance!

```
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <style>
   section {
     height: 100vh;
   }
   .test1 {
     background: grey;
   }
   .name {
     border: 3px solid white;
     color: white;
     padding: 25px 0;
     width: 35%;
   }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="test1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <h1 class="text-center name center-block">Dylan Bailey</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
 </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be all you need if you only have one element on the page. You'll have to remove the default margin that's set by the `h1` tag also.

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1.name {
  border: 3px solid white;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="name">Dylan Bailey</h1>
```

Comment: Wonderful solution. Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem and glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Use property `height` and `line-height` the value of both should be same and this will align the data in the center :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the grid that comes with bootstrap. No CSS needed.

```
<body>
<section class="test1">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <h1 class="text-center name">Dylan Bailey</h1>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/14701/